# How to change the image in the tabbar without going to that viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an IPhone application in which i am using the custom images for the tabbar.when selecting the tabbar i have to show one image and unselecting showing the another.I have successfully implemented that by using the bellow code in the appdelegate.
`

```
 UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinboard_hvr2.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinboard2.png"];



    UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scan_hvr2.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scan2.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"places_hvr2.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"places2.png"];


    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    tabBar.TintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];


    [item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
    [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
```

`but now the problem with me is i have a tutorial view in the secondindex.when clicking on that button i need each of my tabbar icons to be changed according to the explanation in the tutorial.but I dnt need to gothere.I want to stay at the tutorial view itself.but need to change the icons .can anybody help me in achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i have sorted out the problem.actually its a simple thing.set your selected and deselected image according to the tutorial button actions.For example if you have 3 buttons there to show each tabs significance set the selected image of the appdelegate.tabbar according to the view like this.`

```
TabNavAppDelegate *appdelegate = ( TabNavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinboard_hvr2.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scan2.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"places2.png"];
    UITabBar *tabBar = appdelegate.tabBarController.tabBar;
    tabBar.TintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];


    [item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:unselectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
    [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:unselectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
    [item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:selectedImage3];
```

`and in the third button action set it back to normal way as it done in the appdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Send a notification to AppDelegate or call a delegate method. In that method you can also pass your parameters if required and do the specific tab changes over there.

Hope this will work for you.